# Equal voltage, but not shorted?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, short-circuit

This is a fundamental circuit question. Suppose two nodes of a circuit are always kept at the same voltage by some unknown mechanism. If I now connect these two nodes with a wire, would it introduce any changes to the operation of the circuit?

For example, in an *ideal* op-amp, the two input terminals have equal voltage. However, I've heard some say it's incorrect to think these two terminals are shorted. Why is that? If these two terminals are always at the same voltage (as we are assuming an ideal device), shorting them wouldn't make a difference, would it?

Comment: Adding a wire effectively removes the guarantee of low input bias current and allows that current to be anything.  Have a look into how leakage current affects practical op-amp circuits.

Comment: so long as the circuit is hypotheical and the wire is real (has non-zero resistance)  it will make no difference.  else if you want to divide by zero the result is always undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For the question in the first paragraph**

A clarification to my earlier statement. You have to be careful how you explain things. If you assume that "two nodes are **always** kept at the same voltage by some unknown force", then the problem is simply, no it will not have an effect - because as you stated, the two nodes are always kept at the same voltage no matter what - they must be independent of each other for this to be the case.

However, just because two nodes are the same voltage, doesn't mean that a wire will have no effect. In a circuit where two nodes are **dependent** on each other, then just shorting them out may or may not have no effect. Why? because the wire may change the transfer function of the circuit and thus the relationship between the two dependent nodes. This is certainly the case in op-amp circuits where you have feedback.

**In regards to the second paragraph**

Op-amp terminals aren't shorted internally (you can short them externally, but it's not particularly useful to do so). The voltage is not always the same at each terminal - for example you can connect one to one supply rail and the other to the other supply rail. However the effect of having them non-equal is that your op-amp output clamps to one or other of the supply rails. This is because op-amps typically have very high gains - a small difference in input voltage results in a large difference in output voltage.

I think you are confusing concepts. There is an approach with op-amps of negative feedback in which the output feeds back in to the negative input terminal. Any changes made to the input terminal will result in the output value trying to change, but because you have feedback, the output then affects the input which is typically designed so as to bring the input difference back to zero at which point the output stabilises at its new value.

Answer (score 6):

The stable non-saturated solution to an op-amp circuit satisfies equality of voltage across the inputs, but it also satisfies other requirements such as near-zero current into the inputs.

If you add a wire, you replace the restriction with a much weaker one -- that the currents at both inputs are equal and opposite.  This greatly increases the set of possible solutions.

In particular, your assumption that the current through the wire is zero is flawed.  By Ohm's Law,

$$V = IR$$

You want to divide both sides by \$R\$, leaving $$I = V \frac{1}{R} = 0 \frac{1}{R} = 0$$

However, this equation is NOT valid.  Deriving \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$  from \$V = IR\$ is only permitted when \$R \neq 0\$.  For a wire, your derivation causes division by zero.

Ultimately, Ohm's Law is satisfied by any arbitrary value of \$I\$.

Answer (score 5):

The nodes being at the same voltage does not mean that they can be shorted without any ill effects. Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9N7pN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, assuming the opamp is ideal, the voltage on nodes A and B should be the same (equal to 1V).

The current isn't though. The current flowing through R2 is much lower than the current flowing through R1.

If you took out the opamp and just connected nodes A and B together, the voltage would become lower (about 9.9mV).

If you left the opamp in and just shorted A and B together, shorting both inputs of an opamp would make it output 0V and since it has low output impedance, the voltage on both A and B would become zero.

Answer (score 3):

In an op-amp circuit, a feedback network maintains the two inputs at (very nearly) the same voltage. Usually the feedback network around an op-amp assumes two independent KCL equations, where the input current drawn by the op-amp is negligible (on the order of 1nA). But each node has its own independent KCL in this design.

At first, very little current would flow (because the feedback network causes the two inputs to nearly match). But even though very little current would flow at first, shorting the inputs would interfere with correct operation of the feedback network, and the circuit would become unstable. There would be no way for the op-amp to correctly determine the right output voltage to continue to make the two inputs match. So the output would likely saturate at either the positive or negative supply rail.

About the ideal op amp model: As the open-loop gain approaches infinity, the difference between the two inputs approaches zero. But there still must be *some* difference between the inputs, otherwise how can the op amp determine its output voltage? The idea of an ideal op-amp is just a heuristic to make the circuit analysis a bit easier, by looking at just the feedback networks and not worrying about the circuitry inside the op-amp. But it is just a heuristic for analysis, it is not something that could ever exist.

Comment: IMO your last paragraph gives the best answer to the OP's real (but somewhat hidden) question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding shorting two same voltage nodes:
Suppose you can manage two node at same voltage, still if you shorted them there are many effect you have to face:

- Your transfer function may change.
- Your equivalent impedances from those two nodes will change.
- your circuits feedback will effected
- current finds a new path to flow, so operating voltage may change.

Now regarding your Op-amp , if you shorted A & B , there are some consequences too.Like:

- Ideally Op-amp input current zero, so there will be no current flow through resistance R2 . But now it found a new path and current will flow.
- real Op-amp don't have the same voltage at node A & B ,there is always a small difference (maybe in millivolt range ) but when you short them, you give same voltage at those node. So output of the op-amp may oscillate.